# Problems installing on Macbook

Tags: boot, mac, macbook, system-installation

I have a Macbook Pro in which I created a Ubuntu live CD on an external Hard-drive. I completely removed MAC OSX from the hard-drive and just installed Ubuntu.

Later realising that I had installed a 62-bit, which then lead to a whole range of issues. For example:

1) Blank screen on boot-up - I've uninstalled and re-installed the Nvidia drivers

2) Slow and crashes - Crashes would happen when typing something inside the terminal

3) The "windows" or dialog boxes would become extremely blurry and would result in me having to re-start my machine

My plan is to re-install a 32-bit ubuntu operating system, however, I have done this and created this onto the external HD. When loading on the mac, I press the "alt" key, but it just hangs.. It won't let me choose which drive to boot into.

Could anyone offer any suggestions to how I can remove the 64-bit o/s and install a 32bit?